# Razor Html.DisplayNameForInnerType for IEnumerable ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, annotations

I have my View bound to `IEnumerable<MyViewModel>`.

MyViewModel class is annotated with a DisplayName like this:

```
 [DisplayName("My other Display Name")]
    public class MyViewModel
    {
     ...
    }
```

In my views which are directly bound to "MyViewModel" I used `Html.DisplayNameForModel()` and it works.

For the case of IEnumerable... I think `Html.DisplayNameForInnerType...` could be used but unfortunately I cannot help myself to find the expression required here.

Can anyone help with an example of how to use `Html.DisplayNameForInnerType`?

UPDATE1:
To answer a question in the comments: It is about ASP.Net Core 1.1
[image: Html.DisplayNameForInnerType<>]

However, I coulnd't find it in the MS documentation.

Comment: Can you show where do you find `DisplayNameForInnerType`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with DisplayNameForInnerType??? Where does this come from? MVC 5?

Comment: @Wheels73 I have added it to the initial question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that you have the following model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "My Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "My name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In your view you can use Html.DisplayNameForInnerType like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameForInnerType((MyViewModel item) => item.Id)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameForInnerType((MyViewModel item) => item.Name)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to write a custom Html helper, but the easiest way is to use the temporary parameter in Model:

```
    [DisplayName("My other Display Name")]
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("My other Display Name")]
        public string DisplayNameProp { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.DisplayNameProp)</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the class DisplayName

```
@Html.DisplayNameForInnerType((MyViewModel model) => model)
```